# jquery count siblings does not return correct result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings

I want to count the `sibling` by **classes**,

html,

```
<div class="item-sibling">1</div>
<div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">2</div></div>
<div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">3</div></div>
<div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">4</div></div>
<div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">5</div></div>​
```

jquery,

```
var len = $('.item-sibling').siblings().css({background:'red'}).length;
alert(len);​​​​ // return 4
```

it does not include `<div class="item-sibling">1</div>`

how can I include it?

jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ur3s/)

and if I change the html to,

```
<div class="item-sibling">0</div>
<div class="item-sibling">1</div>
<div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">2</div></div>
<div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">3</div></div>
<div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">4</div></div>
<div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">5</div></div>
```

I will get `6` this time. Strange!

**EDIT,**

```
<div class="group-a">
    <div class="item-sibling">1</div>
    <div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">2</div></div>
    <div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">3</div></div>
    <div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">4</div></div>
    <div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">5</div></div>​
</div>


<div class="group-b">
    <div class="item-sibling">1</div>
    <div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">2</div></div>
    <div class="item-holder"><div class="item-sibling">3</div></div>
</div>
```

There are series of groups with the **same class**, and I want to count a targeted group's sibling dynamically for instance the **first group**.

Comment: All `.item-sibling` elements but the first one have siblings... you have 4 `.item-holder` elements which are the siblings of the first `.item-sibling` element. All other `.item-sibling` elements don't have siblings. I think you didn't get the terminology right... what is your actually issue? What are you trying to achieve with that code? *edit:* In the other case you get 6 elements because you get the union of siblings of the first two `.item-sibling` elements.

Comment: what number are you trying to find ? to count the number of elements with the class of `item-sibling` use `$('.item-sibling').lenght`

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, it's vice versa: None of the `.item-sibling` elements but the first one have siblings (couldn't edit anymore).

Comment: And with "sibling" you mean `.item-sibling` elements in that group?

Comment: yes `".item-sibling" elements in that group`.

Comment: That's different than siblings then... "siblings" is a well defined term in the DOM. See [this picture](http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/09/20/relationship-in-the-dom/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
var len = $('.item-sibling').siblings().andSelf().css({background:'red'}).length;
```

Or...

```
var len = $('.item-sibling').parent().children().css({background:'red'}).length;
```

---

Edit: after reading your updated, I would suggest the following:

1) Add a generic "group" class to each group.  E.g.,

```
<div class="group group-a">
    ...
</div>
```

2) Then take advantage of that class to find all "siblings":

```
var len = $('.item-sibling:first').closest('.group')
    .find('.item-sibling').css({background:'red'}).length;
```

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Instead of trying to find a solution to your solution, please explain what your actual problem is. Maybe you don't need/want `.siblings()` at all! Do you just want to count the `.item-sibling` elements?

Comment: After reading your updated question, I have to agree with @Felix - what you are describing isn't really siblings. In your problem, what defines a sibling? What you've really described at this point is just all elements with the same class... which would just be `$('.item-sibling').length`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because siblings are the *others*. Try jQuery [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) which includes the target element to the fetched set.

```
var len = $('.item-sibling')
    .siblings()
    .andSelf()
    .css({background:'red'})
    .length;
```

---

And the second HTML you have, you have 2 `.item-sibling` which are `0` and `1`. jQuery gets `0`'s siblings (`.item-holder`, including `1`) and `1`'s siblings (`.item-holder`, including `0`), which makes 6 all in all.

Comment: [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) is now deprecated as of JQuery 1.8 and it's replacement is [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now that we clarified what you want, if you have a reference to the group, you can simply do:

```
var items = $group.find('.item-sibling').length;
```

If you have a reference to the an `.item-sibling` element, do:

```
var items = $item.closest('.group').find('.item-sibling').length;
```

This assumes that each group has a common class.

If you want to get a list of number of elements in each group, you have to iterate over each group:

```
var num_items = $('.group').map(function() {
    return $(this).find('.item-sibling').length;
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, I also have a solution now `var len = $('.item-sibling').unwrap().siblings().css({background:'red'}).length;
  alert(len);` maybe not as good as yours but it works.

Comment: I don't understand why you keep using `.siblings()`, but if you have fun with it ;)

Comment: my mistake for keeping going on with sibling :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to jquery documentation .

"The original element is not included among the siblings, which is important to remember when we wish to find all elements at a particular level of the DOM tree."

ref : http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count all divs with class="item-sibling", why not just do

```
$('.item-sibling').length;
```

This will count all 5 divs?